# Locale function?

Tags: demandware, salesforce-commerce-cloud

Is there a server side function in SFCC to get Locale?  Thank you!!!

I am localizing a sfcc site, and need to update the en_gb locale in thousands of hard coded strings (in a xml file obtained from Merchant Tools >  Content >  Import & Export) to server side code that will dynamically insert the correct locale, i.e. en_gb, fr_fr, etc.  I know there are a few server side functions like $URL()$ that can run before content is rendered.  Is there one to get the Locale?

here is what I have now... https://www.example.com/en_gb/holiday-sale-event/?prefn1=productType&prefv1=Shoes

ideally, I'm looking for something like: https://www.example.com/$Locale()$/holiday-sale-event/?prefn1=productType&prefv1=Shoes

Expected results would be:

https://www.example.com/en_gb/holiday-sale-event/?prefn1=productType&prefv1=Shoes

https://www.example.com/en_nl/holiday-sale-event/?prefn1=productType&prefv1=Shoes

https://www.example.com/fr_fr/holiday-sale-event/?prefn1=productType&prefv1=Shoes

https://www.example.com/de_de/holiday-sale-event/?prefn1=productType&prefv1=Shoes

...etc., depending on locale.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `$url()$` to generate the URL which will automatically populate the correct locale string in the URL.

Assuming that the above examples are links for a refined category search within a category with the ID: `holiday-sales-event` Then your first example would be represented as such:

```
$url(Search-Show,cgid,holiday-sales-event,prefn1,productType,prefv1,shoes)$
```

This would produce the correct localized URL for whatever locale context the content is being rendered for.

Since the “holiday-sales-event” portion of the URL is likely to be localized itself, then your intended approach would result in either 404s or redirects at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the current locale with request.locale

```
var currentLocale = request.locale;
```